# how to concatenate two items in array of string using java?

Tags: java

I have a text file i already read it and return an array of string "lines" in this structure

```
{(1),text,(2),text,(3),text........}
```

I want to restructure it as

```
{(1)text,(2)text,(3)text........}
```

which mean concatenate every number like (1) with the next text and so on

```
public String[] openFile() throws IOException {

        FileInputStream inStream = new FileInputStream(path);
        InputStreamReader inReader = new InputStreamReader(inStream,"UTF-8");
        BufferedReader textReader = new BufferedReader(inReader);

        int numberOfLine = countLines();
        String[] textData = new String[numberOfLine];

        for (int i = 0; i < numberOfLine; i++) {
            // if (textReader.readLine()!= null) {
            textData[i] = textReader.readLine();
            //}

        }

        textReader.close();
        return textData;

    }
```

how can i do it please using Java language ?
Thanks for your helps and your opinions

Comment: You want to remove this : (1) or (2) or whatever (num) is ?

Comment: When you were asking your question, there was a big orange **How to Format** box to the right, a preview area underneath, and an entire toolbar of formatting buttons. Taking the time to see things are well formatting is only polite when asking for help. (Looks like 'hewo' fixed it for you on this occasion.)

Comment: @RamyMohamed he wants each item in the array to start with "(LineNum)"

Comment: can you write the actual content of the file. Altering the values if that is confidential. Coz I am not getting your question properly

Comment: well if it's always the same format and there are no **)** in your texts you can just replace all **),** with **)**. Not the prettiest solution I guess but it would work

Answer (score 3):

```
String[] newArray = new String[textData.length / 2];

for (int i = 0; i < textData.length - 1; i+=2) {
  newArray[i / 2] = textData[i] + textData[i + 1];
}
```

But be sure that your `textData` has an even length

Put this snippet before the `return` statement and return `newArray` instead;

Comment: Are you sure that this answer is related to the question ?

Comment: yes i am... he wants a new array that concatenates the two lines in one... look at the example

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the comma you want to omit is always preceded by a closing bracket. Assuming that that is the only time it happens in your string you could just do a simple replacement in your for-loop:

```
textData[i] = textData[i].replace("),", ")");
```

If that isn't the case, then another thing you could do is work on the basis that the comma you want to remove is the first in the string:

```
    //Locate index of position of first comma in string
     int firstComma = x.indexOf(',');

     //Edit string by concatenating the bit of the string before the comma 
and the bit after it, stepping over the comma in the process
     textData[i] = (textData[i].substring(0, firstComma)).concat(textData[i].substring(firstComma + 1));
```